# Sequential requests with request-promise

Tags: node.js, promise, node-request

Is there a less-nested way to achieve the following with `request-promise`:

```
r = require('request-promise');

r(url1).then(function(resp1) {
    // Process resp 1

    r(url2 + 'some data from resp1').then(function(resp2) {
        // Process resp 2
        // .....
    });
});
```

Each request is dependent on the result of the last, and so they need to be sequential. However, some of my logic requires up to five sequential requests and it causes quite the nested nightmare.

Am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can return a `Promise` in the `onFulfilled` function provided to `Promise.then`:

```
r = require('request-promise');

r(url1).then(function(resp1) {
    // Process resp 1
    return r(url2 + 'some data from resp1');
}).then(function(resp2) { 
    // resp2 is the resolved value from your second/inner promise
    // Process resp 2
    // .....
});
```

This lets you handle multiple calls without ending up in a nested nightmare ;-)

Additionally, this makes error handling a lot easier, if you don't care which exact `Promise` failed:

```
r = require('request-promise');

r(url1).then(function(resp1) {
    // Process resp 1
    return r(url2 + 'some data from resp1');
}).then(function(resp2) { 
    // resp2 is the resolved value from your second/inner promise
    // Process resp 2
    // ...
    return r(urlN + 'some data from resp2');
}).then(function(respN) {
    // do something with final response
    // ...
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error from any unresolved promise in the above chain
    // ...
});
```

Comment: This is good, but I'm having an issue where it seems like my second request is called twice, and then my third request is called four times. Why might that be?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Setting the `simple` option to `false` looks like it fixed the issue. It might have been because it was by passing my own error handling for requests that weren't 200.